# jsf2 ajax redirect not being fired when additional query parameters are present in redirect to url

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I'm having strange issue with the ajax redirect.  The redirect is not being fired if the redirect url is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><partial-response><redirect url="command?cmd=myaccloginbystaysignedIn&TargetUrl=/MSAMAddressBook.jsf&ErrorPage=errorpage_viewexpired.jsp"></redirect></partial-response>
```

But it is being fired if the redirect url is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><partial-response><redirect url="command?cmd=myaccloginbystaysignedIn"></redirect></partial-response>
```

Any idea why these addition parameters in url is causing redirect to not get fired?
==> &TargetUrl=/MSAMAddressBook.jsf&ErrorPage=errorpage_viewexpired.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of problem.  The problem is caused by the & sign.  I need to be `&amp;`.  So for those additional parameters, it needs to be formatted like this:
`&amp;`TargetUrl=/MSAMAddressBook.jsf`&amp;`ErrorPage=errorpage_viewexpired.jsp